# Touchscreen support for Ubuntu in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, touchscreen

I have seen [the news](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2058329/review-virtualbox-4-3-goes-touchy-feely-for-windows-8-virtualization.html) about VirtualBox adding touchscreen support.

But it seems like this was targeted mainly at Windows 8.

There is also [a thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=61497) over at the Virtual Box forums describing the same problems I am having.

Mainly, that my Ubuntu Guest (on a Ubuntu Host) does not recognize taps, but merely moves the cursor to the place I tapped on the screen. This is with `mouse integration` *enabled*.

With `mouse integration` *disabled* the tapping is recognized, but the cursor has an offset, that seems to depend on the position of the host cursor, when clicking into the window and then only evaluates the motion (direction, acceleration) of the finger and not the actual position on the screen.

Is there a problem with VirtualBox, or maybe with the drivers on my host Ubuntu 14.04.1 machine?

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but the misaligned cursor problem probably stems from the input matrix being calculated when the screen is not at its full resolution, for example while still being in terminal-mode. Try refreshing the screen with `xrandr --auto` or `xrandr --orientation normal`. This solved the misalignment problem for me. Otherwise just keep the kernel updated and if you build your own, don't forget the kernel module [`hid-multitouch`][1]. [1]https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multitouch_displays

Comment: What version of VirtualBox are you using?

Answer (score 1):

i have a dell laptop and it presents the touchscreen as a usb device.

If you want the guest to use the touchscreen device you will need to pass it through to the guest and run the appropriate drivers in the guest.

In the case of ubuntu then xorg should pick it up.

You will need to configure your host os to ignore the touchscreen for this to work, they can't be shared.